# Pure virtual function called C++ in base/derived class

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have this base class:

```
class Base {
public:
  Base();
  virtual ~Base();
protected:
  virtual on_next_item(std::string& item) = 0;
private:
    void read_loop();
};
```

and this derived class:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived();
  virtual ~Derived();
protected:
  void on_next_item(std::string& item) override;
};
```

In the `Base` class constructor I'm starting a thread which reads from a socket and calls `on_next_item()` which is called on the derived class. 
In the `Base` destructor the reader thread is stopped via a atomic flag. 
But sometimes the `read_loop` still calls `on_next_item` and I get a "Pure virtual function called!" error. I assume I'm running in a race condition:

The subclass (object) has already been destructed and thus the function is not registered any more.

Is there a proper way to solve this race condition?

For completeness here's the reader loop:

```
while (running.load())
{
  string item = read();
  if (running.load())
  {
    on_text_item(item);
  }
}
```

The running flag is switched to false in the `Base` class destructor.

Edit (complete running example, has to be executed several times to run in the issue):

```
#include <atomic>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
  Base() : running(true)
  {
    readerThread = new boost::thread(&Base::read_loop, this);
  }

  virtual ~Base()
  {
    running = false;

    delete readerThread;
    readerThread = nullptr;
  }

protected:
  virtual void on_next_item(std::string &item) = 0;

private:
  boost::thread *readerThread;

  void read_loop()
  {
    std::string element = "Element";
    while (running.load())
    {
      boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(2));
      on_next_item(element);
    }
  }

  std::atomic_bool running;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  Derived() : Base()
  {
  }

  virtual ~Derived()
  {
  }

protected:
  virtual void on_next_item(std::string &item)
  {
    std::cout << "On Next Item " << item << std::endl;
  }
};

void constAndDestruct()
{
  Derived d;
  boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(2));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  constAndDestruct();
  boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(2));
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE] as usual please. Anything else would lead to pure speculation.

Comment: You could move the logic from the destructor of `Base` to a member function instead. Or would that not work for you?

Comment: Creating a thread in the constructor does not seem a good idea.  Also in the Base class constructor, the object is not fully formed (derived does not exist yet).  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30258639/when-is-it-safe-to-call-this-in-constructor-and-destructor

Comment: I tried to follow RAII (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization). As a thread is a resource I wanted to init it in the constructor and destroy it in the destructor. Otherwise I would have to provide a "start" and a "stop" method.

Comment: It's natural that the [derived part is destructed before the base destructor gets called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539282/order-of-calling-constructors-destructors-in-inheritance). Does the function need to be pure virtual? if you make the base implementation a no-op, then it is not an issue if it gets called after the derived part is destructed

Comment: Note that you don't need to dynamically allocate the thread here. Just have it as a simple member

Comment: @slawekwin What do you mean by "no-op"? You mean providing a default implementation on the base class?

Comment: @Soccertrash yes, that's what I meant: `virtual void on_next_item(std::string &item) { }`

Answer (score 6):

Calling virtual functions from constructors or destructors is [generally considered a bad idea](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html). The function call will actually be done as if the function were not virtual because at that point the constructor of `Derived` has not yet been called, member variables or `Derived` are still uninitialized...

The obvious solution is to move the logic of your class to a public member function and call that function just after creation of the object:

```
Derived d;
d.run();
```

Comment: Basically I do not call a virtual function from the destructor. It is called from a method running on a thread.

Comment: @rodrigo and the same goes for the object destruction: `Derived::~Derived()` should call a `Base::join()` method to be sure the thread calling `on_next_item()` is stopped before the `Derived` part of `d` is destroyed.

Comment: @Soccertrash You are calling a virtual function from a thead function started from a constructor. The virtual function may be called before or after the `Derived` constructor. It is a race, which is even worse.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following changes-

1. Set the "running" flag to false inside ~Derived() rather than ~Base().
   Change the access level of "running" to protected.

   virtual ~Derived()
      {
          running = false;
      }
2. Remove the sleep from the reader's loop

   while (running.load())
      {
         on_next_item(element);
      }