# Why the `this` pointer worked in constructor in C++?

Tags: c++

I know the `this` pointer will point to the object instance that currently in, but I don't know how to implement it.

And I found that in standard [7.5.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.this#1) said:

> The keyword this names a pointer to the object for which an implicit object member function ([class.mfct.non.static]) is invoked or a non-static data member's initializer ([class.mem]) is evaluated.

but in [12.2.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.funcs#general-2) said constructors do not have implicit object parameter, then why I can use `this` pointer in constructor?

then I have several question comming, so my question is:

1. Does the `this` pointer belongs to the class?

   I think the answer is NO, but I wanna confirm it.
2. Does all class instance shared the constructors and destructor?

   I knew that the class instance will share the member function, does it same on constructors and destructor?
3. How the `this` pointer was implemented?

   Is there something like virtual table to maintain the `this` pointer?
4. Why I can use the `this` pointer in constructor?

   The `this` point to the implicit object, but constructor didn't have the implicit object parameter, then how could the `this` pointer worked well?

Any additional supplements and recommendations are appreciated.

## Edit：

This stackoverflow helps me a lot : [Does a constructor also have an implicit this parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71824507/does-a-constructor-also-have-an-implicit-this-parameter)

Comment: The sentence I suspect you refer to for constructors not having a `this` argument, starts with "For the purposes of overload resolution, ..." That doesn't say constructors doesn't have `this` (or they would not be able to access any non-static members inside the function body).

Comment: please one question per question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is it safe to call this-> in constructor and destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30258639/when-is-it-safe-to-call-this-in-constructor-and-destructor)

Comment: The constructor is invoked when an object is created. The compiler has to know *where* to create the object, and can set the `this` pointer accordingly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude okay, it seems that I misunderstand it, thank you very much :)

Comment: @wohlstad no, but it helps me a lot, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but I don't know how to implement it.

`this` pointer is a feature of the C++ language. If you aren't implementing C++, then you don't need to "implement" `this` pointer. If you want to know how to implement C++, there are open source C++ compilers available.

> why I can use this pointer in constructor?

Constructor is a non-static member function. You can use `this` in non-static member functions.

> but in 12.2.2 said constructors do not have implicit object parameter

Quoted rule is prefaced: **For the purposes of overload resolution...**. It doesn't apply to anything other than overload resolution.

> 1. Does the this pointer belongs to the class?

There is no concept of "belongs" in the language.

> 2. Does all class instance shared the constructors and destructor?

There is no concept of sharing functions in the language.

> 3. How the this pointer was implemented?

The language doesn't describe how to implement itself. It describes how the program written in the language shall or may behave.

> 4. Why I can use the this pointer in constructor?

See above.

Comment: okay thank you very much, For the question 2, I mean Does the `this` pointer a member of class?

Comment: @Mes `this` is not a member.