# Why does invoking a virtual method in constructor and binding a virtual method then calling it later yield different results?

Tags: c++, constructor, virtual-functions, stdbind

This is my code snippet:

```
class Base {
  public:

  Base() {
    foo();
    bind();
  }

  virtual void foo() {
    std::cout << "base foo\n";
  }

  void bind() {
    fn = std::bind(&Base::foo, this);
  };

  std::function<void()> fn;
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:

  void foo() override {
    std::cout << "derived foo\n";
  }

  void bind()  {
  }

  int val;    
};

int main() {
  Base* p = new Derived();
  p->fn();
}
```

The output is:

```
base foo
derived foo
```

`foo()` prints `base foo`, because at this point, the vtable still points to `Base::foo`, according to answers under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30258639/when-is-it-safe-to-call-this-in-constructor-and-destructor).

During the construction of `Base`, the object is not yet of `Derived` class. So, when calling `std::bind()` the `this` pointer is still a pointer to the `Base` class, and the argument pointer is passed in the constructor body of `Base`, so why does `p->fn` call `foo` in the `Derived` class?

My compiler is Apple clang version 14.0.3

Comment: v_ptr points to a new v_table of derived class. https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/the-virtual-table/

Comment: This might look confusing, at first. Don't be discouraged. Keep plugging away, and trying to figure out how virtual functions work in C++. Once you do figure out, and understand everything, you'll be in awe and amazement, as you behold the power of mighty C++ virtual functions.

Comment: You could have removed `Derived::bind()` as well as `Derived::val` since they serve nothing to the question and are not used.

Comment: More or less for the same reason why this would work: `Base* b = new Derived(); b->foo();` . Derived class has it's own virtual table that's pointing to overriden virtual functions.

Comment: I don't think [the proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/why-is-a-call-to-a-virtual-member-function-in-the-constructor-a-non-virtual-call) answers the question asked here, which seems to be about the behavior of a "pointer to base" passed to `std::bind`.

Comment: @pptaszni but I think when construcing base class, this pointer cant be used in dynamic dispatch right？ because at this point, the derived class is not constructed

Comment: @codesavesworld Yes, but at the point you **call** `p->fn()`, the actual derived type is known.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is a call to a virtual member function in the constructor a non-virtual call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/why-is-a-call-to-a-virtual-member-function-in-the-constructor-a-non-virtual-call)

Comment: `std::function` is unimportant here. Whole thing is caused by fact how object is constructed step by step. [With std::function](https://godbolt.org/z/afsToqs3E), [without it](https://godbolt.org/z/1MEW1n6Px).

Comment: @kiner_shah  but when constructing base class, the entries in vtable of derived class still points to function in base class right?

Comment: Put another way, once your `Derived` constructor is called, every pointer to the Base is now a pointer to Derived.  The vtable accessed from that location is a Derived vtable.  That's the "dynamic" part of dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @DrewDormann and that is the point, and should be an answer.

Comment: @codesavesworld Look at [Marek's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77173391/why-do-invoking-a-virtual-method-in-constructor-and-binding-a-virtual-method-the#comment136049650_77173391)'s example without `std::bind`, it'll be more clear.

Comment: @BoP It seems you overlooked the question :)

Comment: @MarekR I understand the code example you gave,  because foo is a virtual function, and p's dynamic type is Derived, but in code listed in the question, doesnt the pointer stored in fn has  dynamic type of Base ?

Comment: The `bind` is **dispatched** using the virtual function table lookup.  There is a different syntax to use if you want to bind to the `Base::foo` in particular, `fn = [this]{ this->Base::foo(); };`.

Comment: @Eljay it is impossible to bypass virtual call. Only compiler can do it if he can determine exact type of object at compile time. So basically your lambda and scope operator doesn't change anything.

Comment: @MarekR • the lambda's body bypasses the virtual call.

Comment: @Eljay prove it on godbolt.

Comment: @MarekR https://godbolt.org/z/d5qbGP53s And it's not only with lambdas. Every time you **call** the fully qualified `Base::foo()` in `Derived`'s implementation, it will bypass the virtual dispatch as well (but I guess you already know that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when called std::bind is still a pointer to Base class, and the argument pointer is passed in constructor body of Base, why p->fn called foo in derived class?

Once your `Derived` constructor is called, every pointer to the `Base` is **now a pointer to `Derived`**. The vtable accessed from that location is now a Derived vtable

That's the "dynamic" part of dynamic dispatch.

Comment: More correctly, every pointer to `Base` is now a pointer to a "`Base` subobject of a `Derived`" (which may not contain the actual address of a `Derived`)

Comment: @codesavesworld the vtable pointer is changed **immediately before** a derived constructor is called.

Answer (score 6):

`std::bind` (or any other usage of pointer-to-member-function where the member function in question is `virtual`) doesn't bind to a particular function.  Rather when used with a virtual member function, it binds to a virtual dispatch slot<sup>1</sup> (i.e. vtable slot on common implementations which use a vtable).

So after the vtable is reconfigured by more derived constructors, the function found through the `bind` result functor changes.

---

<sup>1</sup> There are a few reasons that pointer-to-member-function types are fat, containing more than just a code address, and the need to be able to virtually dispatch is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Just because I was a bit bored, and to show that there is no magic involved, here is a very simplified (and working) illustration of how things can work behind the scenes (there is a lot more going on in the real world, but the principle is the same):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base;

// Roll our own "bind + std::function" simplification.
struct Bind {
    Base* b;   // "this"
    size_t fn; // Index in function table.
    void operator()();
};

using member_fn = void(*)(Base*); // Limit to one type of member function.

struct Base
{
    member_fn* v_table;
    Bind fn;
};

void Bind::operator()() { b->v_table[fn](b); }

struct Derived : Base {};

void Base_foo(Base* self) { std::cout << "base foo\n"; }
void Base_bind(Base* self) { self->fn = { self, 0 }; } // foo is the first function.
member_fn Base_vtable[] = { Base_foo, Base_bind };

void Derived_foo_impl(Derived* self) { std::cout << "derived foo\n"; }
void Derived_foo(Base* self) { Derived_foo_impl(static_cast<Derived*>(self)); }
void Derived_bind_impl(Base* self) {}
void Derived_bind(Base* self) { Derived_bind_impl(static_cast<Derived*>(self)); }
member_fn Derived_vtable[] = { Derived_foo, Derived_bind };

void init_base(Base* self)
{
    self->v_table = Base_vtable;
    self->v_table[0](self); // foo()
    self->v_table[1](self); // bind()
}

void init_derived(Derived* self)
{
    init_base(static_cast<Base*>(self));
    self->v_table = Derived_vtable; // Now we are not a Base any more...
}

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    init_derived(&d);
    Base* b = static_cast<Base*>(&d);
    b->fn();
}
```